# Python/AWS Parameter Store: updated SSM values

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

Let's say I have a AWS SSM called `/config/db` withe following values:

```
{
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": "3306"
}
```

now I need to add the following
item(s) to the same SSM

```
{
  "my_version": "1.0"
}
```

How can I use the Python/boto3 package to archive this action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use the `put_parameter` method to update (overwrite) the parameter.

You grab the old one, parse the JSON object then add the required attributes (my_version) and update the parameter with the serialized (json.dumps) value.

```py
import boto3
import json

client = boto3.client('ssm')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    old_parameter = client.get_parameter(Name='/config/db')
    print(old_parameter)
    parameter_value = json.loads(old_parameter['Parameter']['Value'])
    parameter_value['my_version'] = '1.0'
    client.put_parameter(Name='/config/db', Overwrite=True, Value=json.dumps(parameter_value))
```

Do not forget the required IAM permissions to update the parameter.